# How can I create a Chrome extension to read the daily Blinkist on one page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, infinite-scroll

**Background:**

I would like to create a Chrome extension that allows me to read the [Blinkist Daily](https://app.blinkist.com/en/daily) article on one page. By default, it is split into several pages that I need to navigate through using the navigation controls at the bottom of the article page.

**Question:**

What are the steps I need to consider in order to develop a Chrome extension that implements infinite scroll (a one-page reading experience) on the abovementioned website?

Comment: There are many tutorials. Don't forget to read the official overview and architecture and examine the official sample extensions. Currently, the question is too broad, nonspecific.

Comment: See the tag info for the links: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome-extension/info

Comment: @orschiro: how about asking the folks of blinkist to provided the option to read it on one page.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I already contacted support. They told me that this feature is not high on their agenda, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using simple CSS extension like Stylebot? Just show the hidden chapters and adopt the look so that it pleases you. Stylebot also allows sharing that style with others...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian! I am completely unexperienced. How do I best get started?

Comment: Well simply read through the extension and see how it applies CSS to certain websites. For CSS it should be a simple `display: block` on the respective element